# Launch a View(Window) after UserControl is Loaded in WPF using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dispatcher

I have a main window which hosts two views (user controls). One is `UserControl1` and the other is `UserControl2` following a toggle system.

`UserControl1` loads first and then the view can be toggled. I wish to launch a window after `UserControl1` is loaded.

I am launching views using the messaging pattern and registering the views in `app.xaml` or `MainView.xaml`.

How should I proceed?

**Xaml for my MainView:**

```
    <Window x:Class="CustomListView.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:CustomView="clr-namespace:CustomListView"
        Title="MainView"
        Width="300"
        Height="300">
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <CustomView:RelayKeyBinding Key="F12"  CommandBinding="{Binding Path=Toggle}"></CustomView:RelayKeyBinding>
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ExecutionView">
            <CustomView:ExecutionView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ConfigView">
            <CustomView:ConfigView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style x:Key="mainContentControlStyle"
               TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Mode}"
                             Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ConfigView}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Mode}"
                             Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ExecutionView}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"
                        Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=mainContentControlStyle}" />        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

If you require any more code I'll be happy to post it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an [EventTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger.aspx) to convert the Loaded event of the Window into a command execution, then create your window there. This would be my code:

```
<UserControl>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UserControl_LoadedCommand"} />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</UserControl>
```

If you are using [MVVM Light](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/), this is the code:

```
<UserControl>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <Galasoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding UserControl_LoadedCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying... will the Event to command fire....Execute and CanExecute Methods in ViewModel ??

Comment: Yes, they will. MVVM Light has the documentation for setting that up.